# How to change theme in native base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm currently new in react native and tried to use native base, the component is good but I'm in stuck to change the theme in native base while I know how to use style but not all of them can be applied in native base (such as change color in active footer tab). Even it can be customize in style I would prefer to change in theme just like in the doc. But I can't overcome this.

I've tried to use my custom Themes and applied in my component so far but it didn't change.

My Workspace:
-react-native 2.0.1
-native-base 2.3.1

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code and read [here](https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theaming-nb-headref) for more information:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Text, StyleProvider } from 'native-base';
import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components';
import material from './native-base-theme/variables/material';
​export default class ThemeExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>
        <Container>
          <Content>
            <Text>
              I have changed the text color.
            </Text>
          </Content>
        </Container>
      </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a file called myThemes.js with the code above and run this command  node node_modules/native-base/ejectTheme.js after that I tried to run or import myThemes and there's an error Unexpected character " (5:0)

Comment: do you want to customize the theme?

Comment: Yes, I've been following the tutorial but can't get through with it

Comment: I've seen that page before and can't get the light.js maybe you can give some example?

Comment: do we need to add StyleProvider on each page or can we add it centrally?

Comment: your whole app must be wrapped by StyleProvider. If you have a root component you can use it once.

Comment: doing this absolutely destroys vs codes typescript IntelliSense. Such a bummer.

Answer (score 4):

Run this command i.e. **node node_modules/native-base/ejectTheme.js** in the project root directory.
After running this command a folder with named native-base-them will be created to your project root.